# Laravel Through Relationship

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Given below are the tables I have:

```
keywords
--------
id
keyword
```

Keyword table has many footprints

```
footprints
----------
id 
keyword_id
footprint
```

Each serp is associated with a footprint

```
serps
-----
id
footprint_id
phrase
```

I need to get the keyword each serp is associated with. By reading about Laravel's Has One through relationship, I get the feeling that it can be done with  [has one trough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through) relationship.

I want to get the keyword using:

```
  $serp->keyword;
```

On Serp Model, I wrote the following code which is not working. I will highly appreciate your help to the write right relationship code.

```
class Serp extends Model {
 //

 public function keyword(){
     return $this->hasOneThrough(
     '\App\Keyword',
     'App\Footprint') ;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can use has one through to find Serp based on keyword

```
class Keyword extends Model {
    public function serp(){
        return $this->hasOneThrough(
            '\App\Serp',
            'App\Footprint') ;
    }
}
```

But if you want to use $serp->keyword(), you should use inverse relationship of hasOneThrough.

Check this [trait](https://github.com/staudenmeir/belongs-to-through) out, it might help you